# Integral$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{-1}^{1} |x + y|\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lV4zu.png) is the question.

I put the equation in the following double integral:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{-1}^{1} |x + y|\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$$

I know you can break up the absolute function into the following. I'm not really sure what to do next. I looked at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285434/double-integral-of-an-absolute-function) link but I don't know when x + y is nonnegative and when it's negative as we need the values of both x and y and when calculating the inner integral we're only doing it with respect to y. So I'm not exactly sure how to determine when |x + y| is nonnegative and when it is negative. 
$$ 
   |\,x + y\,| = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       x + y & : x + y >0 \Leftrightarrow y > -x \\
       -(x + y) & : x + y < 0 \Leftrightarrow y < -x
     \end{array}
   \right.
 $$

However, I came up with a "solution" which is quite silly but I thought it might work.

$$\int_{0}^{1} | \int_{-1}^{1} x \, dy \, + \int_{-1}^{1} y \,dy\, | = \int_{0}^{1}  |\, 2x\, |  = 1 $$

I'm lost and any help would be greately appreciated.

Comment: Please add the question into the question body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint, applying your formula for $|x+y|$ gives:
$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{-1}^{1} |x + y|\,dy\,dx =
\int_{0}^{1} \int_{-1}^{-x} [-(x + y)]\,dy\,dx + \int_{0}^{1} \int_{-x}^{1} (x + y)\,dy\,dx $$

Comment: Thank you so much! I finally got the answer!!

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
$\ds{{\cal I} \equiv \int_{0}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}\verts{x + y}\,\dd y\,\dd x
     = \int_{0}^{1}{\cal F}\pars{x}\,\dd x\quad\mbox{where}\quad
     {\cal F}\pars{x} \equiv \int_{-1}^{1}\verts{x + y}\,\dd y}$

> \begin{align}
> {\cal F}\pars{x}
> &= \left.\vphantom{\LARGE A}\verts{x + y}\,y\,\right\vert_{y\ =\ -1}^{y\ =\ 1}
>    - \int_{-1}^{1}y\sgn\pars{x + y}\,\dd y
> \\[3mm]&=
> \verts{x + 1} + \verts{x - 1}
> -\bracks{%
> \left.\vphantom{\LARGE A}\sgn\pars{x + y}\,{y^{2} \over 2}
> \right\vert_{y\ =\ -1}^{y\ =\ 1}}
> +
> \int_{-1}^{1}{y^{2} \over 2}\bracks{2\delta\pars{x + y}}\,\dd y
> \\[3mm]&=
> \verts{x + 1} + \verts{x - 1} - {1 \over 2}\,\sgn\pars{x + 1} +
> {1 \over 2}\,\sgn\pars{x - 1}
> + x^{2}\Theta\pars{1 - \verts{x}}
> \end{align}

$$
{\cal F}\pars{x}
=
\verts{x + 1} + \verts{x - 1} - {1 \over 2}\,\sgn\pars{x + 1} +
{1 \over 2}\,\sgn\pars{x - 1} + x^{2}\Theta\pars{1 - \verts{x}}
$$

> \begin{align}
> {\cal I}&=
> \int_{1}^{2}{1 \over 2}\,\verts{x}\,\dd x
> +
> \int_{-1}^{0}{1 \over 2}\,\verts{x}\,\dd x -\int_{1}^{2}\sgn\pars{x}\,\dd x
> +
> \int_{-1}^{0}\sgn\pars{x}\,\dd x + \int_{0}^{1}x^{2}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=
> \left.{x^{2} \over 4}\right\vert_{1}^{2}
> -
> \left.{x^{2} \over 4}\right\vert_{-1}^{0} 
> -
> \left.x\right\vert_{1}^{2}
> +
> \left.\pars{-x}\right\vert_{-1}^{0} + \left.{x^{3} \over 3}\right\vert_{1}^{2}
> \\[3mm]&=
> \pars{1 - {1 \over 4}} - \pars{-\,{1 \over 4}} - 1 - 1
> + \pars{{8 \over 3} - {1 \over 3}}
> =
> {4 \over 3}
> \end{align}

$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}\verts{x + y}\,\dd y\,\dd x = {4 \over 3}
}
$$